# How to make restfull service truely Highly Available with Hardware load balancer

Tags: rest, cluster-computing, load-balancing, high-availability

When we have a cluster of machines behind a load balancer (lb), generally hardware load balancer have persistent connections,

Now when we need to deploy some update on all machines (rolling update), the way to do is by bringing one machine Out of rotation, looks for no request sent to that server via lb. When the app reached no request state then update manually.

With 70-80 servers in picture this becomes very painful.

Can someone have a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

70-80 servers is a very horizontally scaled implementation... good job! Better is a very relative term, hopefully one of these suggestions count as "better".

1. Implement an intelligent health check for the application with the ability to adjust the health check while the application is running. What we do is have the health check start failing while the application is running just fine. This allows the load balancer to automatically take the system out of rotation. Our stop scripts query the load balancer to make sure that it is out of rotation and then shuts down normally which allows the existing connections to drain.
2. Batch multiple groups of systems together. I am assuming that you have 70 servers to handle peak load. This means that you should be able to restart several at a time. A standard way to do this is to implement a simple token granting service with a maximum of 10 tokens. Have your shutdown scripts checkout a token before continuing.
3. Another way to do this is with blue/green deploys. That means that you have an entire second server farm and then once the second server farm is updated switch load balancing to point to the new server farm.
4. This is an alternate to option 3. Install both versions of the app on the same servers and then have an internal proxy service (like haproxy) switch the connections between the version of the app that is deployed. For example:

haproxy listening on 8080
app version 0.1 listening on 9001
app version 0.2 listening on 9002

Once you are happy with the deploy of app version 0.2 switch haproxy to send traffic to 9002. When you release version 0.3 then switch load balancing back to 9001 etc.